# Table Data is not destroying when Navigating through Routing SAP UI5

Tags: routes, sapui5, master-detail

I have a split app screen with two master and two detail screen. I have a table in 1st Detail Page. After pressing a button in 1st detail page, I am navigating to second detail page. Here I am doing some actions. But when I navigate from 2nd detail page to 1st detail page(which contains table), table data is not destroying. I tried .setData(null). but still data is there. Kindly suggest some ideas.

Note: I am using Routing for navigation

Regards
Karthik S

Answer (score 0):

Do you need to delete the record from table? If so, Please use .setProperty("/", null) instead of .setData to your local table model.

Like: this.getModel("oLocalModel").setProperty("/path", null);

Comment: instead of null set the property to an Array eg: this.getModel("oLocalModel").setProperty("/path", []);